# If Form has '_blank' attribute, how to handle the close event for that window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, html-target

I have used a form submit (post method) in which form is submitted in new window of the browser, as form's attribute target is set to `_blank`. I want to do some code as soon as the new window is closed.

I want to know how can we handle the close event of the new window, so that I can perform the next operation.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592827/detect-new-tab-closing-from-parentopener

Comment: @pete Thanks. Updated the question. Actually in my case window opens after form is submitted clicking on button, with the post method. I am not being able to track the new window. So if can get the access to that new window, I may get ahead to handle the close event.

Comment: You need to open the window first, then post the form to that window. You need that to provide the JS reference to the new window. Pete's suggestion is a good one. Then don't use "_blank", use the named window reference.

Comment: Thanks @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane. Did the same. Worked for me.